# How to override Bootstrap 4 grid with scss without editing any bootstrap files?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Can I simply regenerate the grid (or any other part of boostrap) and override the default bootstrap settings with scss without changing any files and variables in the original bootstrap for easy updating in the future?

Answer (score 6):

After spending some time on this, and found no similar answers, I thought I would share the steps to do it:

1) It's not enough to include bootstrap from the cloud like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

You can still load it like this in your project, and override it later, but you will need the scss sources to generate your own grid (and whatever else you want to customize).

2) If you haven't done it yet, you'll need to `npm init` first to setup the package.json in your project folder. Install the latest bootstrap to the project using `npm install bootstrap`.  You'll probably also want to `npm install node-sass`, for compiling your project's scss to css.

3) Given the following folder structure:

```
|
|-- assets
|   |-- css
|   |-- scss
|   |   |-- mystyle
|   |   |   |-- _variables.scss
|   |   |   |-- ...other scss files
|   |   mystyle.scss
|-- node_modules
|   |-- bootstrap
package.json
```

In your main `mystyle.scss` file, you'll need to @import the Bootstrap grid files:

```
/* Before your custom variables file, import Bootstrap functions */
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

/* your custom variables file */
@import "mystyle/variables"

/* Import the rest of Boostrap's dependencies */
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/grid-framework";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/grid";

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/display";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/flex";

/* import the rest of your own project's files ... */
```

4) In your own **variables file**, include the variables needed by Boostrap to genereate the grid:

```
// Bootstrap 4 grid override

// Grid breakpoints
//
// Define the minimum dimensions at which your layout will change,
// adapting to different screen sizes, for use in media queries.

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1230px
);

@include _assert-ascending($grid-breakpoints, "$grid-breakpoints");
@include _assert-starts-at-zero($grid-breakpoints);


// Grid containers
//
// Define the maximum width of `.container` for different screen sizes.

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1200px
);

@include _assert-ascending($container-max-widths, "$container-max-widths");


// Grid columns
//
// Set the number of columns and specify the width of the gutters.

$grid-columns:                12;
$grid-gutter-width:           24px;

$enable-grid-classes:       true;
```

5) Generate your css with `node-sass assets/scss -o assets/css` and include `mystyle.css` **after** the bootstrap css to ovverride its default values.

**--Bonus--**

6) If you want `node-scss` to watch and auto-compile your changes to the scss files, in the **scripts** section of your project's `package.json` file add an **scss** command, under the **test** command, as it’s shown below:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "scss": "node-sass --watch assets/scss -o assets/css"
}
```

Run it with `npm run scss`.

More detailed explanation about auto compiling is [in this atricle](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/watch-and-compile-sass-in-five-quick-steps--cms-28275).

Comment: Bootstrap uses Autoprefixer to add vendor prefixes during compilation, so you should also install and run that after you've compiled the SCSS to CSS. In this way you ensure better cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: If you need an example, I made a Gist about this a while ago: https://gist.github.com/Klooven/39e0143d63b5f4efca34c994e94770fa